# validation for input type number with minimum and maximum range

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to validate if the input type number crosses the range.

```
<input type="number" min="-10" max="10"  required="true" message="you can give score -10 to +10 only">
```

I tried `required = true` but not working i want to show if the value crosses the range show message like **you can give score `-10 to +10` only**

I want to allow while entering itself, not when submitting.

How can i do that..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at this jsfiddle i have created.
[https://jsfiddle.net/6bkws7zd/](https://jsfiddle.net/6bkws7zd)

HTML

```
<input id="txtNumber" type="number" message="you can give score -10 to +10 only" />
<span id="errorMsg" style="display:none;">you can give score -10 to +10 only</span>
```

Jquery

```
$("#txtNumber" ).keyup(function() {
  if($('#txtNumber').val()<-10 || $('#txtNumber').val()>10 ){
      $('#errorMsg').show();
  }
  else{
    $('#errorMsg').hide();
  }
});
```

You can add required field to input control if you want to make it required.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of hard coding "10" and "-10" in your function, you can get the min and max values from the element and check if it's within range.

```
$(function () {
   $( "input" ).change(function() {
   var max = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
   var min = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
   if ($(this).val() > max)
   {
      $(this).val(max);
   }
   else if ($(this).val() < min)
   {
      $(this).val(min);
   }       
 }); 
});
```

@Caspian also provided a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ddk67/75/

Comment: I think that additionally to the `change` event you should also wire up the `keyup` event. Otherwise it's possible to manually enter a value which exceeds the max or is below the min and there is no correction or adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

This is the vanilla js way.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e=>{
  const el = e.target || e

  if(el.type == "number" && el.max && el.min ){
    let value = parseInt(el.value)
    el.value = value // for 000 like input cleanup to 0
    let max = parseInt(el.max)
    let min = parseInt(el.min)
    if ( value > max ) el.value = el.max
    if ( value < min ) el.value = el.min
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="-10" max="10"  required="true" title="you can give score -10 to +10 only">
```

Comment: I like your approach. showing the reverse value as validation.

Comment: Cannot input negative sign with keyboard first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    var max = parseFloat($(this).attr('max'));
    var min = parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));
    if (parseFloat($(this).val()) > max) {
        $(this).val(max);
    } else if (parseFloat($(this).val()) < min) {
        $(this).val(min);
    }
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what your code does with comments or additional commentary.